# R: given Sys.Date(), find date-time of most recent, historical, Friday

Tags: r

Given a `Sys.time()`, I want to return the date-time of the most recent, historical Friday.

For example, given the Sys.time() below:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2022-03-23 18:59:26 EDT"
```

I want:

```
"2022-03-18 00:00:00 -03"
```

(Notice that I set `tz = "Etc/GMT+3"`)

Is what I want possible? If so, where might I start?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the fact that `POSIXlt` contains the weekday (Monday is `1`):

```r
today <- Sys.Date()
dput(as.POSIXlt(today))
# structure(list(sec = 0, min = 0L, hour = 0L, mday = 23L, mon = 2L, 
#     year = 122L, wday = 3L, yday = 81L, isdst = 0L), class = c("POSIXlt", 
# "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
(as.POSIXlt(today)$wday - 5) %% 7
# [1] 5
today - 5
# [1] "2022-03-18"
format(today - 5, format = "%a")
# [1] "Fri"
```

This works identically with `POSIXt` objects, not just `Date` objects:

```r
now <- Sys.time()
(as.POSIXlt(now)$wday - 5) %% 7
# [1] 5
```